# HTTPS - cannot generate sitemap

Tags: https, sitemaps

Does any of you have experienced problems with generating the sitemap due to using https instead of http?

I have 2 webshops (each own installation). One of those have a ssl certificate and uses https. I have added this code in the .htaccess to make the whole site use https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Everytime I try to generate sitemap it gives me an error that it's unable to generate the sitemap

while on the other installation (which do not use https) I can generate it no problem

that's why I'm concluding at the moment that there is something wrong with the https settings but I have no clue how to fix it

Comment: What error? How are generating it? Of course you've checked file system permissions?

Comment: Try removing the htaccess lines you posted and enter your https address under System - Configuration - Web - Unsecure Base URL as well as Secure Base URL.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your replies, when I create sitemap via - Catalog - Google sitemap - it creates the sitemap.xml (I can access it via ftp, but it's empty) the file permission is 666. Magento gives me the error "Unable to generate the sitemap" I have removed the code from my .htaccess file and added https to the secure/unsecure base url but it still doesn't generate the sitemap. Just have to add that the site works perfectly fine and uses https.

Comment: You could try to use `/media/` as a path for the sitemap.xml, because you should have write permissions on this folder. Although it should not be a permission problem if the file is created. If this does not help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "sitemap.xml" as the filename? Magento gives you the option to enter a custom filename, but for some reason it will throw an error when you enter a different name.

If you have multiple stores, you can add them in different folders (like /en_US/ and /fr_FR/) and still set the filename to sitemap.xml.

If that isn't working either, there is something wrong with the write permissions of  your file (or the owner).